# How to use serve index with function instead template

Tags: node.js, templates, express

Hi i want to render template from custom function using serve-index, but if i pass function to "template:" i get error "string required". What i can do?

```
var app = require("express");
var serveIndex = require("serve-index");

app.use('/ftp', serveIndex('public/ftp', {
'icons': true,
'template': function(){}// and this is my problem, what i shuld write this?


}))

app().listen(3000)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the function you're trying to use. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: i want to render  template from custom function but i dont know how?;p

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you're intending to use express without instantiating it first, but, once I added code to instantiate it, and implemented the correct function signature for the template call back, it seems to work.

```
var express = require("express");
var serveIndex = require("serve-index");

var app = express();

app.use('/ftp', serveIndex('/tmp/ftp', {
  'icons': true,
  'template': function(locals, cb){
     cb(null, "<html><body><h1>It could WORK!!!</h1></body></html>");
}}));

app.listen(3000)
```